# retrieving value from add_action in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook

I am trying to call an action inside the filter. I want to retrieve a value from the action method and use it for the filter function

```
   add_filter( 'wc_product_table_query_args', 'wcpt_custom_query_args', 10, 3 );

function wcpt_custom_query_args( $args, $product_table) {
add_action('dokan_store_profile_frame_after', 'add_store_id', 13, 2);
        ;

    // do something with $args
$args += array('author' => $store_id);

    return $args;
}

function add_store_id($store_user, $store_info){
    $store_id = $store_user->ID;    
    return $store_id;

}
```

How can I retrieve the $store_id inside the function wcpt_custom_query_args?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    add_action('dokan_store_profile_frame_after', 'add_store_id', 13, 2);

function add_store_id($store_user, $store_info){
    global $store_id;
    $store_id = $store_user->ID;    
    add_filter( 'wc_product_table_query_args', 'wcpt_custom_query_args', 10, 2 );
}

function wcpt_custom_query_args( $args, $product_table) {
global $store_id;
    // do something with $args
$args += array('author' => $store_id);

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Please first load add_store_id after than wcpt_custom_query_args funciton

Comment: Thanks a lot ... by loading add_store_id function it worked :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You should find in your source code the line `apply_filter('wc_product_table_query_args'` to look for the params allowed. If 3rd param is $store_id then you can use that.

One thing you should remember, on action hook, nothing should be returned (return only for filter hook)

Comment: apply_filter('wc_product_table_query_args' consist only two parameter and none of them is $store_id

Comment: Can you try to var_dump $args, $product_table to see any param can be used to get $store_user and $store_id?

Comment: No couldn't guess from these parameters